# how to scroll the treelistcontrol to the selected item

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress, treelist

is it possible to scroll the treelistcontrol to the selected item. so that selected items are always in view. I am programmatically selecting nodes using the call to SelectItem(nodeToSelect) by extending the treelistcontrol. A code snippet or a sample would be very helpful.

Comment: `A code snippet or a sample would be very helpful`.

Comment: Found my answer, there is a method ScrollIntoView in the TreeListView.

Comment: TreeListView? Where did you get that from?

Comment: I peeked into the Devexpress source code.

Comment: You mentioned in the question TreeListControl from devexpress...... and then you mention TreeListview.    TreeListControl has BringintoView method and TreeListView has ScrollIntoView.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BringIntoView method.

More documentation on this on devexpress:http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/DevExpressXpfGridTreeListControlMembersTopicAll

Also msdn information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110.aspx

```
private void OnTreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  TreeViewItem item = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
  if (item != null)
   {        
    item.BringIntoView();
   }
}
```